# Fussy logic asymmetry

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebra

Consider "False", "maybe", "True" group table.
(1) "True" is a unitary element upon AND. (always returns the other element)
(2) "False" is a unitary element upon OR.

I feel, I am missing an operation that makes "maybe" a unitary element.

That is
(@) "maybe?X=X?maybe = X".

Is there such operation over this group?

Comment: If there was such a thing as a group table with "maybe" in it, I don't think it would serve any purpose.

Comment: @Accelerator See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Kleene_and_Priest_logics

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like "Fussy logic" should refer to something much more stringent than fuzzy logic.

Comment: I don't know if such an operation has been named, but you can find a few operations that fit your criterion by building their truth tables. What other properties do you want this operation to have in relation to AND and OR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches to fuzzy logic. What you are looking for can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic).
The truth value of a statement $p$ is given by
$$t\in[0,1]$$
which means:
If $t=0$, the statement is absolutely false

If $t=1$ the statement is absolutely true

and $t\in (0,1)$, the higher $t$ is, the more likely the statement is true which is your maybe.

Comment: I am looking for symmetry. An operation that makes "maybe" a unitary element, much like "True" is a unitary element under "AND" operation.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by symmetry because this can be symmetric in the sence that if $p$ has a $t$ truth value then $\sim p$ has a $1-t$ truth value. Are you talking about $3$ valued logic? Because this will not be fuzzy logic

Comment: The title is confusing but the question is clearly neither about fuzzy logic nor symetry